# Benchmark Node.js Ghost with JMeter

Tags: node.js, jmeter, ghost

I try to Benchmark Node.js Ghost with JMeter. I want to create a testplan which just signs in and then creates and publishes a post.

My problem now is that i do not get any session-cookies. So every request on the backend fails. I already tried to change the CookieManager settings within the user.properties file.

i tried following configuration:

```
CookieManager.check.cookies=false
CookieManager.delete_null_cookies=false
CookieManager.save.cookies=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
```

This is the results tree (on the left side you can see my testplan setup):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Ghost uses cookies at all, the errors you're seeing are likely due to failed login.

Looking into response to the first request:

[image: GHost response]

It seems Ghost uses [OAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) authentication.

So you need to do the following:

1. Extract this `access_token` value from the `/ghost/api/v0.1/authentication/token` request response. You can do it using JSON Path PostProcessor like

   [image: JSON Path PostPRocessor]
2. Configure [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) for next requests to send `Authorization` header with the value of `Bearer ${access_token}`

   [image: HTTP Header Manager]

The whole process of getting dynamic content from previous request, converting it to JMeter Variable and adding as a parameter to next request is known as [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations).

Comment: Is there any example test plan with working authentication for ghost?

Comment: You can see it above %)